# Code first generate nullable columns for Required fileds

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, .net-5

I have the next C# code first class fields definition (.NET 5):

```
[Required]
public Visa Visa { get; set; }

[Required]
public Embassy Embassy { get; set; }
```

Despite of Require attribute EF generates nullable DB columns:

```
VisaId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true),
EmbassyId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true),
```

How to fix this and make it NOT NULL? In other classes similar code and it works as expected.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Any fluent configuration not shown here? Or explicit nullable FK properties (like `public int? VisaId { get; set; }`)?

Comment: Hi Ivan, in Snapshot I get only like: 

b.Property<int?>("VisaId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");
b.Property<int?>("EmbassyId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

Comment: So I'm looking the way to get table.Column<int>(nullable: false) in migration

Comment: That's strange, since snapshot and migration should match. Have you tried to `Remove-Migration` and `Add-Migration` again?

Comment: Hi Ivan. Yes I did. Tried to remove and re-add migration. Now installing updates for VS :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not specifying your foreign key in your entity, EFCore will generate a shadow property that will be nullable by default (as you are currently seeing in .NET 5).

If you stay on .NET 5 there are a couple of ways to generate non-nullable columns for your entities.

We can explicitly make the foreign key property.

```cs
public int VisaId { get; set; }
public Visa Visa { get; set; }
```

Or you can specify it fluently in your DbContext and use `IsRequired()`.

```cs
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Visa> Visas { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property<int>("VisaId").IsRequired();
    }
}
```

If you are not stuck on .NET 5 and can move to .NET 6, EFCore is fully NRT annotated and will make your migrations as such. Add `<Nullable>enable<Nullable>` to your project file or at the top of your entity file add `#nullable enable`. Regenerate your migration and you should see that the auto-generated columns are non nullable.

Update:

I've done a little more investigating to try and recreate your original situation where your original classes do have some non-nullable columns.

It seemsl like the `[Required]` annotation is really dependent on both the target framework and the version of EFCore you are using.

Here are my example classes

```cs
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Visa> Visas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("this is one bad connectiong string");
        }
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Visa
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Visa Visa { get; set; }
        public Country Country { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm using an SDK-style console app to generate migrations.

In **ALL** of the following frameworks and efcore versions, enabling [Nullable Contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts) makes the columns be generated with their annotated nullability. This is the simplest fix IMO.

Using `net48`, `netcoreapp3.1`, `net5.0`, or `net6.0` and EFCore 3.1.21, the `Required` annotation **does** have an effect.

The relevant generated table:

```
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Persons",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    VisaId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    CountryId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)
                },
```

I just update the TFM and EFCore version, delete the existing migrations and regenerate them.
Here's my summarized findings in table form

| TFM | EFCore | nullable: VisaId | nullable: CountryId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| net48, netcoreapp3.1, net5.0, net6.0 | 3.1.21 | false | true |
| netcoreapp3.1, net5.0, net6.0 | 5.0.12 | true | true |
| net6.0 | 6.0.0 | false | true |

Hopefully that helps clarify your situation!

Comment: The curious thing is that in my neighbouring class I have:
`
        [Required]
        public Country Country { get; set; }
`
and it generates:

`
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "CountryId",
                table: "Embassy",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: 0);
`

but in Snapshot
`
                    b.Property<int?>("CountryId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");
`

And these classes are almost similar in their descriptions :)

Comment: Did you happen to generate the other migrations on another target framework or efcore version?

If I change my test project to net48 (which only supports up to EFCore 3.1), then the `Required` annotations actually do make the columns non-nullable without specifying the shadow property manually.

Comment: @smatveev Check my update. I think you may find it useful.

Comment: Thank you for the update Hank. It's briliant! That's exactly what I was dealing with